# constantly receive warning `Unknown or uninitialised column: 'date'`

Tags: r, rstudio

I constantly receive the warning message `Unknown or uninitialised column: 'date'`.

This even happens if I'm in a fresh start of R with no data frames, no data at all. I might be using R strictly as a calculator and enter something like `(4*27)^3` and I'll get the warning. If I enter the exact same command again there's no warning. I don't save any history upon exit when shutting down R Studio.

This happens across my Windows and Linux systems, which use R Studio 1.1.463. I'm running R 3.5.1. Don't know what to do at this point. Been happening for months intermittently.

My .Rprofile

```
local({
  r = getOption("repos")             
  r["CRAN"] = "https://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/"
  options(repos = r)
})
```

My .Renviron

```
R_LIBS=C:/Users/stackinator/Documents/R-libraries
```

Comment: Can you give us a reproducible example?  Off the top of my head, it sounds like maybe you are running some other script, of which perhaps you are not aware.

Comment: What is in your system-wide Rprofile or `~/.Rprofile`? Is there an R session RData file lying around?

Comment: I don't use any .Rprofile, I do have my .Renviron create a custom library directory. That's about it. I don't save any type of history upon exit. Other than that I can open a fresh session of R and literally type `1 + 1` and get the warning. It's intermittent though.

Comment: If this happens during a session, you can set options(warn=2) and options(error=recover) and it will put you into recovery mode when the warning is thrown.  Then you can see where it is happening.  If you add this info, we may be able to help better.